# "Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int]" in Project Euler exercise

Tags: haskell

I'd like help doing it "my way" because i can google other solutions if i want to know better/more Haskellic ways to do it

Now I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int]
```

Here is my thought, but somewhere it is wrong. How does one go about when sending accumulators (I've thought back and forth having it in the "base case" or not)

My thinking is that i select one of the coins, and then adding all others in separate recursions and seeing if it is equal to 200, if so then that is what i want to add to my results, if lower, add the coin to the list eg `[100,50]` and then recurse the same way. If above 200, return null/empty or whatever. `Hand` is what i call the added coins so far

```
module Main where

coins = [100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

euler31 :: Int
euler31 = 1 + length (twoPoundCombinations)

twoPoundCombinations = recursion [] [[]]

recursion :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]],
recursion hand result
    | sum hand == 200 = [hand]
    | sum hand  > 200 = [[]]
    | sum hand  < 200 = result ++ map (\x -> recursion (x:hand) [[]]) coins
```

Comment: `1x£1 + 1x50p + 2x20p + 1x5p + 1x2p + 3x1p`. this is how they show us what they mean by "one way to get 2 pounds in coins". This translates to `[(100,1),(50,1),(20,2),(5,1),(2,1),(1,3)]` and should be counted only *once*. If you generate your solutions in *this* form, it's OK to count them by taking `length`, as long as all such lists are unique, kept ordered by the pairs' first elements. But I notice you don't bother representing the unique solution `[(200,1)]`, instead just counting it as ready made `1` in your function, kind of a shortcut...

Comment: Well that is what I count, the length of the list of hands (now with duplicates as Daniel Fischer told me, and I'm aware of already).

What i mean is i get (or want to get) the result as [[100,50,50],[100,100]], and then length will give me the nr of "hands"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map (\x -> recursion (x:hand) [[]]) coins
```

would have type `[[[Int]]]`. That's one layer of `[]` too much.

```
result ++ concat (map (\x -> recursion (x:hand) [[]]) coins)
```

would have the right type.

(But your approach would take ages and not give the correct result.)

Comment: could you explain why it will not work? I thikn that if i build 7 trees with each coin as a root, each spawning 7 branches. And if those branches is == 200, then add to results. If <200, then spawn 7 branches again. If > 200 don't add to results, but terminate branch.

Comment: Two things. First, you get a lot of `[]` in your result. Second, permutations. You count e.g. `[1,1,2]` and `[2,1,1]` as two ways to get 4p.

Comment: How can I not add [], but still break? I was thinking, for the naive solution, to sort all list and do nub. Also I'm thinking of limiting coins later, sending only a filtered list of choises where ``filter (\x -> ((sum hand) + x) <= 200) [coins]``

Comment: You get rid of the `[]`s by simply using `[]` everywhere you used `[[]]`. Regarding sorting and `nub`bing, you will - unless I miscalculated - get 23605209427717177391422967983790010220492941499 ways to make 200 from the coins including permutations. That won't finish while the sun still shines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later. I would rather see it fail myself and then do a better solution. As they say, "you learn by making mistakes", then of course I have to make those mistakes myself and learn something :)